# ValueError: You are trying to offload the whole model to the disk. Please use the `disk_offload` function instead

Tags: python, nlp, large-language-model, pre-trained-model, llama

I am trying to run a GitHub project on my computer.
[GitHub Repo that I am trying to run](https://github.com/suryanshgupta9933/Law-GPT)

This is the code snippet that is causing errors.

Steps I took for replicating the project are:

> 1. Cloned the repository.
> 2. Generated the Hugging Face access token
> 3. Added `offload_folder` and `offload_dict_state` after reading the Hugging Face guide to load huge models.

```
def load_llm():
    """
    Load the LLM
    """
    # Model ID
    repo_id = 'meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf'
    login(token="hf_xxxxxxxx")
    # Load the model
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        repo_id,
        device_map='auto',
        load_in_4bit=False,
        token = True,
        offload_folder = r"C:\Users\DHRUV\Desktop\New folder\Law-GPT",
        offload_state_dict = True
    )

    # Load the tokenizer
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(
        repo_id,
        use_fast=True
    )

    # Create pipeline
    pipe = pipeline(
        'text-generation',
        model=model,
        tokenizer=tokenizer,
        max_length=512
    )

    # Load the LLM
    llm = HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline=pipe)

    return llm
```

The Error I am facing, Please help:

```
Token will not been saved to git credential helper. Pass `add_to_git_credential=True` if you want to set the git credential as well.
Token is valid (permission: read).
Your token has been saved to C:\Users\DHRUV\.cache\huggingface\token
Login successful
Loading checkpoint shards: 100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 2/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DHRUV\Desktop\New folder\Law-GPT\app.py", line 5, in <module>
    chain = qa_pipeline()
  File "C:\Users\DHRUV\Desktop\New folder\Law-GPT\utils.py", line 100, in qa_pipeline
    llm = load_llm()
  File "C:\Users\DHRUV\Desktop\New folder\Law-GPT\utils.py", line 44, in load_llm
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
  File "C:\Users\DHRUV\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\transformers\models\auto\auto_factory.py", line 566, in from_pretrained
    return model_class.from_pretrained(
  File "C:\Users\DHRUV\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\transformers\modeling_utils.py", line 3773, in from_pretrained
    dispatch_model(model, **device_map_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DHRUV\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\accelerate\big_modeling.py", line 438, in dispatch_model
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: You are trying to offload the whole model to the disk. Please use the `disk_offload` function instead.
```

Comment: Instead of linking to an external repository, can you create a [mre], list all the steps you took, and the error you are facing as a result? That will make it easier for others to help you. Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you should download the model to you local macheine use huggface_hub,

Comment: @JoshuaShew Thanks for the suggestion. I have added the necessary things to help you understand it better.